# How do you find someone on Facebook by a photo?

Tags: facebook

Suppose I have a photo on my computer taken many years ago. How do I find this person on Facebook using that photo? It has no URL and wasn't taken off of Facebook.

I heard of the [URL method](https://www.facebook.com/notes/arfaoui-firas/find-any-facebook-profile-by-using-picture/212991338733055?ref=nf). However, the photo on my computer contains no URL but may be uploaded publically to his profile. I don't even have any clue how to find his profile but is there a way to search a person from a photo without the photo URL?

Answer (score 1):

Well, AFAIK there is no direct method for Facebook.

But you can do a trick, Google provides the facility of “Search by Image”, utilise it, and analyse the result. Which is the most common thing occurs in the result, try to search it on Facebook. And if you have a older photo of someone, then you will know something about him/her. So give it a try using Google's result and your information about that person.

Comment: I tried dragging one of my public Facebook photos to Google but it didn't seem to work. It was 4 years old and was always public and will be seen on my timeline but guess it didn't work. Also, some sites may not actually keep a copy of the photo in google search right?

Comment: Google keeps updating its search contents according to its Search Rank method. So, if any content has low rank, then it is not displayed on first 2-3 pages, it may go beyond it.

Comment: Yeah but I tried but there wasn't any page selection. It only showed "Visually similar images", which for sure was not even close.

Comment: Hmm, then there is no chance of getting the person, except the Government data server and surely they won't give you access to it. Instead of use trial n error method using the person name on Social Network.